# Linked List Addition/Subtraction Functions are changing the values of arguments?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, linked-list

So in my main, I have two polynomials A and B, and I'm trying to add the polynomials, output the new polynomial and then subtract the polynomial B from A then output. But the problem is that after the addition function, when I call the subtraction function it's performing the subtraction on the summed polynomials instead of a fresh polynomial A and B.

The calls in main

```
outfile << "Printing addition of the first polynomial and the second polynomial" << endl << endl;
linkedList polynomialD;
polynomialD = polynomialD.polynomialAddition(polynomialA, polynomialB);
polynomialD.printList(outfile);

outfile << endl;
outfile << "Printing subtraction of the second polynomial from the first polynomial" << endl << endl;
linkedList polynomialE;
polynomialE = polynomialE.polynomialSubtraction(polynomialA, polynomialB);
polynomialE.printList(outfile);
```

This is what my program outputs:

```
Polynomial in canonical form - 
(6x^6) + (9x^2) + (-5)

Polynomial in canonical form - 
(7x^7) + (2x^5) + (7x^2) + (12)

Printing addition of the first polynomial and the second polynomial

Polynomial in canonical form - 
(7x^7) + (6x^6) + (2x^5) + (16x^2) + (7)


Printing subtraction of the second polynomial from the first polynomial

Polynomial in canonical form - 
(0x^7) + (6x^6) + (0x^5) + (9x^2) + (-5)
```

But it SHOULD print:

```
Polynomial in canonical form - 
(6x^6) + (9x^2) + (-5)

Polynomial in canonical form - 
(7x^7) + (2x^5) + (7x^2) + (12)

Printing addition of the first polynomial and the second polynomial

Polynomial in canonical form - 
(7x^7) + (6x^6) + (2x^5) + (16x^2) + (7)


Printing subtraction of the second polynomial from the first polynomial

Polynomial in canonical form - 
(-7x^7) + (6x^6) + (-2x^5) + (2x^2) + (-17)
```

For some reason the addition function is making it act like it exists so when it's trying to do the subtraction it finds that the nodes currently exist, where it shouldn't.

```
//Function to insert into the linked list
void listInsert(int coefficient, int exponent)
{
    Node *spot = findSpot (coefficient, exponent);

    if(spot->exponent == exponent )
    {
        int temp;
        temp = spot->coefficient + coefficient;
        spot->coefficient = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(coefficient, exponent);
        newNode->next = spot->next;
        spot->next = newNode;
    }
}

//Function used to insert into the linked list but subtracting like powers.
void listInsertSubtraction(int coefficient, int exponent)
{
    Node *spot = findSpot (coefficient, exponent);

    if(spot->exponent == exponent )
    {
        int temp;
        temp = spot->coefficient - coefficient;
        spot->coefficient = temp;        
    }
    else
    {
        int tempcoeff;
        tempcoeff = -coefficient;

        Node* newNode = new Node(coefficient, exponent);
        newNode->next = spot->next;
        spot->next = newNode;
    }
}

//Function to add two polynomials.
linkedList polynomialAddition (linkedList& polynomialA, linkedList& polynomialB)
{
    linkedList newPolynomial = polynomialA;

    //Temporary Nodes point to the first element of each linked list.
    Node* tempNodeB = polynomialB.listHead->next;

    while (tempNodeB != NULL)
    {
        newPolynomial.listInsert (tempNodeB->coefficient, tempNodeB->exponent);
        tempNodeB = tempNodeB->next;
    }
    return newPolynomial;
}

//Function to subtract the 2nd polynomial from the first polynomial.
linkedList polynomialSubtraction (linkedList& polynomialA, linkedList& polynomialB)
{
    linkedList newPolynomial = polynomialA;

    //Temporary Nodes point to the first element of each linked list.
    Node* tempNodeB = polynomialB.listHead->next;

    while (tempNodeB != NULL)
    {
        newPolynomial.listInsertSubtraction (tempNodeB->coefficient, tempNodeB->exponent);
        tempNodeB = tempNodeB->next; 
    }
    return newPolynomial;
}
```

I tried messing around and changing arguments being passed into by reference, as a pointer, having the return changed to pointer instead of value, but when I try to run it, it just says run failed.

edit: Adding findSpot function

```
Node* findSpot (int coefficient, int exponent)
{
    Node *spot = listHead;

    while(spot->next != NULL && spot->next->exponent >= exponent)
    {
        spot = spot->next;
    }

  return spot;  
}
```

And a pastebin link to the whole code if it's needed - http://pastebin.com/yL85Xif2

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you think `findSpot` is important, you're right. Include it, and anything else required for **us** to copy/paste your code to an editor, compile it, and reproduce your problem. Stress the *anything else*.

Comment: I added the findSpot function. I guess I could've copy and pasted the whole code with all the constructors and everything but I felt like it would be too unwieldy to read?

Comment: Looks like your assignment is about linked lists and less about Polynomial addition.  If it were the latter, you would have used `std::list` and get on with the actual goal, which is representing polynomials.

Comment: What do the copy constructor and assignment operator of `linkedList` do? You write your code as if they perform a deep copy, but the outcome strongly suggests that they perform a shallow copy instead - that is, produce another object pointing to the same chain of nodes as the original one. Then, of course, any changes to that chain of nodes affect both objects.

Comment: Oh, I haven't actually made a copy constructor or overloaded the assignment operator. I haven't learned what a copy constructor is, so I guess that it is indeed a shallow copy.

Comment: @user2444400 So you were given an assignment to code a linked list, but not told of the basic functions required to make such a class (copy constructor and assignment operator)?  That's like asking an out-of-shape person to run a marathon.

Answer (score 2):

For me when you do `linkedList newPolynomial = polynomialA;`, you are not creating a new list but, using `polynomialA` list.

If you print your `polynomialA` after the addition you will see that it has been modified, that why after your substraction you get something like `0x^7`.
To keep your algorithm, you should make a copy of `polynomialA` and use it as `newPolynomial`.

Comment: Here's where I'm confused I guess. by doing linkedList newPolynomial =   polynomialA; I figured I was already making a copy of it, but I guess not. How do I make an actual copy of it? And yeah, when I printed out A's list after the addition, it was indeed changed.

Comment: You make a copy by implementing copy constructor and assignment operators for the class.  Once implemented correctly, then `=` will work as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I did some reading about it and I got it to work. Thanks. That took longer than expected. Wihtout the copy constructor and assignment overloading I spent a long time messing around with changing pointers and other various things that didn't work.